# Question about Changing Passphrase

Tags: bitcoin-core, passphrase

In Bitcoin Core, the previous password is required in order to change to a newer password. **Is this previous password used simply as a proof-of-ownership key** (that doesn’t do anything but show proper access), or does it have any part in changing the password through a method of decryption or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a superficial gate-keeping password. The password on your wallet is an encryption passphrase.

Related answer with more details: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/89278/26873

Comment: So, are you basically saying that the old password is required to change to the new password, because it is used to decrypt the file? And then the file is encrypted by the new password?

Comment: Yes, in order to encrypt your wallet with a new password, you must decrypt it first with the existing password.